# Tensorflow 2.0 leaking memory when `input_shape` is specified in keras layer

Tags: python, keras, memory-leaks, tensorflow2.0

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 with keras APIs. There are situations where I need to generate multiple models within the same program execution (say, a cross-validation type of situation). When I generate these models without specifying the input shape, as in the following code snippet, there is no memory leak.

```py
import time

from tensorflow import keras


for _ in range(100):
    model = keras.model.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.kayers.Dense(120, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

[image: Total memory with no input shape specified]

However, if I specify the input shape when adding the first layer of the model, it seems like models are piling up in memory, without being destroyed when not needed. It also seems like the execution time  increases quite a lot.

```py
import time

from tensorflow import keras


for _ in range(100):
    model = keras.model.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.kayers.Dense(120, activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 10)))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

[image: Total memory with input shape specified]

I also generated a list of all the objects for the 2 code snippets, using `Pympler`.

```py
from pympler import muppy
from pympler import summary


...

all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
occupancy = summary.summarize(all_objects)
summary.print_(occupancy)
```

For the models generated without input shape, here is the result:

```
                                                                   types |   # objects |   total size
======================================================================== | =========== | ============
                                                             <class 'str |       79278 |     14.02 MB
                                                            <class 'dict |       14468 |      6.93 MB
                                                            <class 'code |       25252 |      3.49 MB
                                                            <class 'type |        2582 |      2.57 MB
                                                            <class 'list |        8573 |    944.06 KB
                                                           <class 'tuple |       12079 |    796.21 KB
                                                             <class 'set |         732 |    466.12 KB
                                                         <class 'weakref |        4475 |    349.61 KB
                                                     <class 'abc.ABCMeta |         341 |    346.27 KB
                     <class 'tensorflow.core.framework.op_def_pb2.ArgDef |        3822 |    328.45 KB
  <class 'google.protobuf.pyext.cpp_message.GeneratedProtocolMessageType |         369 |    320.16 KB
                                                            <class 'cell |        5921 |    277.55 KB
                                                     function (__init__) |        1694 |    224.98 KB
                                                        <class 'property |        2466 |    192.66 KB
                                              <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        2353 |    183.83 KB
```

And here is the snapshot for the models generated with the input shape.

```
                                                           types |   # objects |   total size
================================================================ | =========== | ============
                                                   <class 'tuple |      296304 |     26.77 MB
                                                    <class 'dict |       71296 |     16.14 MB
                                                     <class 'str |       84828 |     14.54 MB
                                                     <class 'int |      395032 |     10.55 MB
                                                    <class 'list |       98027 |      9.89 MB
                                                    <class 'code |       25281 |      3.49 MB
                                                    <class 'type |        2587 |      2.58 MB
                                                     <class 'set |        2944 |    975.00 KB
               <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation |       14100 |    771.09 KB
    <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation._InputList |       14100 |    771.09 KB
                  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor |       14100 |    771.09 KB
  <class 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TF_Output |       13200 |    721.88 KB
                                            <class 'SwigPyObject |       14100 |    660.94 KB
                                 <class 'collections.OrderedDict |        1262 |    622.22 KB
                                                 <class 'weakref |        6127 |    478.67 KB
```

Is there anything wrong I'm doing? According with the relevant [keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape), the input shape should be somehow provided to the layer (the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#input_shape) about input shape says that if the layer has multiple inputs, the shape is not needed), however, my code still works fine without specifying the input shape. I'm afraid this might be a bug in Tensorflow 2, but honestly I don't really know what's wrong.

**Notes**

- Memory graphs are generated with the `memory_profiler` package.
- Memory snapshots are generated with the `Pympler` package.
- Python 3.7.1 is used.
- OS is Linux Elementary (Ubuntu).

Thank you for your support.

Comment: TensorFlow 2.0 is still an alpha version, so yes, there are bugs. You should file an Issue in github, not really ask a question here.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. I just wasn't sure this is a bug that depends on TF. Anyway I created a [new issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28844) on GitHub.

Comment: It is also possible that, since you are looping the addition of layers and the number of model parameters is multiple of your input size, there is a high possibility of an increase in the size of model parameters, thereby memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time after the post, but I found that my massive memory leak with TensorFlow.Keras was solved by just adding the line:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

To the start of each iteration.
TensorFlow 2.0, Windows, Python 3.6/Anaconda

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to follow up on this one, but the guys from Tensorflow actually solved the mystery for me: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28844

Comment: Thanks yes, I had a different cause I think, but it seems the same fix!